# Producing sound output to sound input in real time

Tags: audio, artificial-intelligence, accessibility

I would like to know whether there exists a program for voice which responds to voice input, producing voice, simultaneously, as voice is input (sounds, words, any type of sound produced with the mouth is input, and the computer, at the same time, produces voice output that responds in some way, in some pattern, even using artificial intelligence, to produce output).

What computing power is required for this? What kind of professors, how many, and what kind of computer?

I ask because I use Google keyboard, for something different (at least in part), (analyzing and computing text in response to sounds).

Has any work been done in this area?

Thanks.